# Create a new column from other column data n row behind

Tags: r

How to create a column as "B" from A so that it reads the data from last nth row of A. For example given n=3 B would be like:

```
    A      B
1   100    NA
2   110    NA
3   88     NA
4   68     100
5   70     110 
6   118    88
7   200    68 
.    .     .
.    .     .
300 77     related value of A in row 300-3
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do this taking `n = 3`

```
n <- 3
```

1) Base R

```
df$B <- c(rep(NA, n), head(df$A, -n))
```

2) `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(B = lag(A, n))
```

3) `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, B:= shift(A, n)]
```

Comment: And what if I want to add all the previous lags into one cell? So each cell in B equals to sum(lag(df$A, 3))?

Comment: @Sean Do you mean `df %>% 
  mutate(B = lag(A, n, default = 0), 
         C = cumsum(B))
` ?

Comment: I mean in the same example, instead of calling a row with n lag, put the sum of the previous n lag so that row 4 of B return sum of the previous 3 rows in A. I think what you said does the same.